# Backup/Zip all server files once to local hard drive

Tags: linux, backup, debian, unix

I have backup2l scheduled to take daily backups that are stored on an external server, this work fine although I would also like to take a full backup of the whole server and store this on my local PC.

How can I do this with minimal errors or big downtime? I mean I dont want the database to become corrupt while I am downloading if it changes half way through, do I need to shutdown most processes? Is there any advice you can give.

I have a fairly default debian lamp setup.

Also is it better to zip everything before I download? 
Should I take care of security by protecting the data for this one time?

Comment: are you using LVM? If yes, how much free space do you have?

Comment: No I dont have LVM installed but I know I have over 100Gb free space, I did a "du" command and I only use 16Gb in total.

Comment: Can anybody advice on the best solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a backup of the database before you do the rsync.  I would omit the working directory of the database & rsync the rest of the machine.  As Hubert Kario said, you should run the rsync at least a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Then I'd suggest rsyncing the data off the server under normal load.

When the first rsync finishes, you down all services you can and perform a second rsync, preferably in single user mode.

Of course, it's unmaintainable but should be OK for a once off situation.